# Flutter: generic list handles different key, value pairs

Tags: list, dictionary, flutter, key

I have a class that has a generic List as property, that I have to initialize, and that has a function that returns a card using that list:

```
class buildCard{
buildCard(this.list);
final List list;

Widget buildCard(int position) {
      return Card(child: ListTile(title: list[position].name,),);
}
```

Now, as you can see, I use

```
 list[position].name
```

that works for the majority of the stuff that I have, but, in case I will have a list which doesn't have "name" as key, I will have some troubles. How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mix both previous answers to get what you want (credit goes to @GünterZöchbauer)

```
abstract class Named {
  String name;
}

class Person implements Named {
  String name;

  Person(this.name);
}

class NotAPerson {
  String noName;

  NotAPerson(this.noName);
}

class BuildCard {
  BuildCard(this.list);
  final List list;

  Widget buildCard(int position) {
    if(list[position] is Named) {
      return Card(child: ListTile(title: list[position].name,),);
    } else { 
      return Card(child: ListTile(title: list[position].noName,),);
    }
  }
}

main() {
  BuildCard b = BuildCard([Person, NotAPerson]);
  b.buildCard(0); // Will access name
  b.buildCard(1); // Will not access name
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `is` to check the type

```
Widget buildCard() {
  if(list[position].name is List) {
    return Card(child: ListTile(title: list[position][0].name,),); // or similar - I don't know your exact structure
  } else { 
    return Card(child: ListTile(title: list[position].name,),);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. If you're checking if "name" is a valid key for that list, why you check if it is a List type?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand your question but it doesn't provide much information. "I will have a list which doesn't have "name" as key" doesn't make much sense because a `List` doesn't have a `name` property.

Comment: Yes, sorry. The List is actually a list of person like List<Person> and Person has the "name" property. So, I was wondering how to generalize it, making that work in case I have, for example, a List<Stuff> where there is no "name" property

Comment: You can't check if it has a property, you can just check if it the item is of specific type. `if(list[position] is Person) {...} else if(list[position] is Stuff) { ...}`

Comment: You could create an interface `abstract class NamedItem { String get name; }` and use `class Person implements NamedItem {...}` and `class Pet implements NamedItem {...}` and then only check `if(list[position] is NamedItem) {...} else {...}`

Comment: I've added an example of code doing exactly what @GünterZöchbauer suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You could constrain your `List` so only objects that have the name property can be passed in.

```
abstract class Named {
    Widget name;
}

class buildCard {
    buildCard(this.list);
    final List<Named> list;

    Widget buildCard(int position) {
      return Card(child: ListTile(title: list[position].name,),);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about this, but the problem is that I want to achieve the opposite, I don't want to constrain my list, but I want to "generalize" it